# How to get all dictionary words from a list of letters?

Tags: c++, permutation

I have an input string, like `"fairy"`, and I need to get the English words that can be formed from it. Here's an example:

> 5: Fairy 
> 4: Fray, Airy, Fair, Fiar 
> 3: Fay, fry, arf, ary, far, etc.

I have an `std::unordered_set<std::string>` of dictionary words so I can easily iterate over it. I've created permutations before as shown below:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> permutations;

// Finds every permutation (non-duplicate arrangement of letters)
std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
do {
    // Check if the word is a valid dictionary word first
    permutations.insert(letters);
} while (std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));
```

That's perfect for length 5. I can check each `letters` to see if it matches and I end up with `"fairy"`, which is the only 5 letter word that can be found from those letters.

How could I find words of a smaller length? I'm guessing it has to do with permutations as well, but I wasn't sure how to implement it.

Comment: I propose first as dictionary sorted_letter -> words, so you don't need permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep an auxiliary data structure and add a special symbol to mark an end-of-line:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::list<int> l = {-1, 0 ,1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::string s = "fairy";
    std::set<std::string> words;
    do {
        std::string temp = "";
        for (auto e : l)
            if (e != -1) temp += s[e];
            else break;
        words.insert(temp);
    } while(std::next_permutation(l.begin(), l.end()));
}
```

Here the special symbol is `-1`

Comment: Very creative! I like your algorithm a lot and it seems to be the fastest option available.

Comment: @CodingScienc: I doubt it is the fastest. for one letter "word" as `"f"` you do useless permutations (you insert `"f"` `4!` times).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have to ask yourself a question. Can you reuse letters? For instance, if you're given the word `friend`, is `fee` legal? `Friend` has 1 `e` and `fee` has 2. That's an important but minor detail.

Algorithm 1: Brute Force

You can iterate over your entire list of possible words and write a method "does this word consist only of letters in this other word"? If so, add it to your final list.

That algorithm changes very slightly based on your answer to the first question, but it's not hard to write.

Algorithm 2: Recursive Approach

Create a method addWords().

```
/**
 * letters is the list of letters you're allowed to use
 * word may not be empty
 */
void addWords(string letters, string word) {
    size_t length = word.length();

    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
         string newWord = word + letters[index];
         string remainingLetters = letters.substr(0, index) + letters(index + 1);
         // if newword is in your dictionary, add it to the output
         ...
         addWords(remainingLetters, newWord);
    }
}
```

Let's look how this works with addWords("fairy", "") --

First loop: add `f` to the empty string and check if `f` is a word.
Then recurse with addWords("airy", f"). We'll look at recursion shortly.

Second loop: add `a` to the empty string and check if `a` is a word. It is, so we'll add it to the output and recurse with addWords("firy", "a").

Repeat, checking each one-letter word (5 times total).

Now, let's look at one level of recursion -- addWords("airy", "f"). Now, we're going to try in order `fa`, `fi`, etc. Then we'll recurse again with something like addWords("iry", "fa") (etc).

From recursing the second loop, we would try words beginning with a instead of f. So we would end up testing `af`, `ai`, etc.

This works if the answer to your first question is "no, we don't reuse letters". This method does NOT work if the answer is yes.

Comment: I like your approaches. I can reuse letters so the brute force example seems quite applicable - I hadn't thought of that. I actually have quite a lot of experience with brute force programs so implementation should be easy and relatively resource-light since I only need to search through my dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can check every prefix (or suffix, you need only be consistent) of each permutation. This will consider some substrings multiple times, but it's a simple change.

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> permutations;

// Finds every permutation (non-duplicate arrangement of letters)
std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
do {
    std::string_view view = letters;
    for (auto i = 1; i < view.size(); ++i) {
        auto prefix = view.substr(0, i);
        // check if prefix is dictionary word
        permutations.insert(prefix);
    }
} while (std::next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically, you can use something like a counter to generate all subsets of your word, and then find all the permutations:

For example:

```
00000 ---> null
00001 ---> y
00010 ---> r
00011 ---> ry
00100 ---> i
00101 ---> iy
...
11110 ---> Fair
11111 ---> Fairy
```

Note: Now, do your permutation function for each word to generate other orders of the chars. See here for the [permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

For implementing the counter, use something like a boolean array, and change the lowest bit, and update others if it needs. In each level, choose those "chars" that their indices are true in your boolean array.

Comment: This constrains the permutations by order of the source string, though e.g. `Fray` would never be generated.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I told him/her that for each word, he/she needs to do a permutation as well.

Comment: You should show how to do that, then.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError As you can see in his code, he has a function for his permutation. His question actually was generating smaller words I think.

Comment: Permutation link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Answer (score 0):

[Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be an appropriate structure to store the word.

I suggest also to use sorted anagram as "key" instead of the word directly:

```
class Node
{
public:
    std::map<char, Node> children; // Might be an array<std::unique_ptr<Node>, 26>

    std::set<std::string> data; // List of word valid with anagram
    // Traditionally, Trie would use instead ` bool endOfWord = false;`

    Node() = default;

    const Node* get(char c) const
    {
        auto it = children.find(c);

        if (it == children.end()) {
            return nullptr;   
        }
        return &it->second;
    }
};

class Trie
{
    Node root;
public:
 
    void add(const std::string& word)
    {
        std::string sorted = word;
        std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
        Node* node = &root;
        for (const char c : sorted) {
            node = &node->children[c];
        }
        node->data.insert(word);
    }
// ...
};
```

Then to print all anagrams you might do:

```
void print_valid_words(std::string letters) const
{
    std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
    print_valid_words(&root, letters);
}
    
private:

void print_valid_words(const Node* current, std::string_view letters) const
{
    if (current == nullptr) return;

    for (auto word : current->data) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;   
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0 || letters[i] != letters[i - 1]) {
            print_valid_words(current->get(letters[i]), letters.substr(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e16305cf4c37347)