# most efficient way to find all the anagrams of each word in a list

Tags: python, c++, c, performance, anagram

I have been trying to create a program that can find all the anagrams(in the list) for each word in the text file (which contain about ~370k words seperated by '\n').

I've already written the code in python. And it took me about an hour to run. And was just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

My code

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

ls = open("words.txt","r").readlines()
ls = [i[:-1] for i in ls]
ls = [[i,''.join(sorted(i))] for i in ls]
ln = set([len(i[1]) for i in tqdm(ls)])

df = {}
for l in tqdm(ln):
    df[l] = [i for i in ls if len(i[0]) == l]

full = {}
for m in  tqdm(ls):
    if full.get(m[0]) == None:
        temp = []
        for i in df[len(m[0])]:
            if i[1] == m[1] and i[0] != m[0]:
                temp.append(i[0])
        for i in temp:
            full[i] = temp
```

if there are more efficient ways of writing this in other languages (Rust, C, C++, Java ...) It would be really helpful if you can also post that `:)`

Comment: There are definitely multiple duplicates for this question. The answer is to sort each word, so `tops` and `pots` and `stop` all became `opst` and can be searched from a dictionary of 4-letter words.

Comment: Related to [how-to-get-all-dictionary-words-from-a-list-of-letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101355/how-to-get-all-dictionary-words-from-a-list-of-letters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the word sorted alphabetically by character as a search key is the direction to go. And maybe you are already doing this (I hardly ever use python) with this line in your code :

```
[[i,''.join(sorted(i))] for i in ls]
```

Anyway this is my c++ take on your problem.
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/_gauHBd_3

```
#include <algorithm>        // for sorting
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>    // for storing words/anagrams
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

// create a class that will hold all words
class dictionary_t
{
public:
    // load a text file with one word per line
    void load(const std::string& filename)
    {
        std::ifstream file{ filename };
        std::string word;

        while (file >> word)
        {
            add_anagram(word);
        }
    }

    auto& find_anagrams(const std::string& word)
    {
        const auto key = get_key(word);

        // intentionally allow an empty entry to be made if word has no anagrams yet
        // for readability easier error handling (not for space/time efficiency)
        auto& anagrams = m_anagrams[key];

        return anagrams;
    }

    // show all anagrams for a word
    void show_anagrams(const std::string& word)
    {
        std::cout << "anagrams for word '" << word << "' are : ";
        auto anagrams = find_anagrams(word);

        for (const auto& anagram : anagrams)
        {
            if (anagram != word)
            {
                std::cout << anagram << " ";
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

private:
    // this function is key to the whole idea
    // two words are anagrams if they sort their letters
    // to the same order. e.g. beast and betas both sort (alphabetically) to abest 
    std::string get_key(const std::string& word)
    {
        std::string key{ word };
        // all anagrams sort to the same order of characters.
        std::sort(key.begin(), key.end()); 
        return key;
    }

    void add_anagram(const std::string& word)
    {
        // find the vector of anagrams for this word
        auto& anagrams = find_anagrams(word);

        // then add word to it (I use a set so all words will be unique even
        // if input file contains duplicates)
        anagrams.insert(word);
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> m_anagrams;
};


int main()
{
    dictionary_t dictionary;
    dictionary.load("words.txt");

    dictionary.show_anagrams("beast");
    dictionary.show_anagrams("tacos");

    return 0;
}
```